# Additional examples of measuring length in 'whole people in Halachah

Tags: sukkah, shiurim-measurements

> אמר ר' יוחנן: סוכה העשויה ככבשן, אם יש בהקיפה
>   כדי לישב בה כ"ד בני אדם כשרה ואם לאו פסולה.
>
> Rabbi Yoḥanan said: With regard to a sukka that is shaped like a furnace and is completely round, if its circumference has sufficient space for twenty-four people to sit in it, it is fit, and if not, it is unfit. ([Succah 7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.7b.19?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi)).

What are additional Talmudic examples of measuring Halachic lengths in *whole* people (nor parts)?

Comment: This isn't a measurement of length but of capacity, which is a sort of volume. This kind of measurement is used in the English-speaking world to this day

Comment: Why do you want to know this? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: First, R'Yoḥanan is talking about [_area_, not _circumference_](https://aphar.dreamwidth.org/177761.html) - the translation is faulty. Second, if you look just below this text, each sitting person takes an area of 1x1 amot, so they are _not_ measuring _lengths_ in persons.